# Generalization of familiar theorem about singular homology to general model category

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

I have two questions, the first one is just wether the following statement is true or not? Is there a reference for this?

[image]

The second question is maybe related, I don't know. But anyway, given $U:\Delta \rightarrow C$, we can construct

$$S:C \rightarrow \text{s}\textbf{Set}$$

given by

$$S(c)_n = \operatorname{Hom}(U_n,c)$$

Given a monomorphism $B \rightarrow Y$ in some category $D$, define $Y/B$ as the pushout of $*_D \leftarrow B \rightarrow Y $ where $*_D$ is the terminal object. My question is this: What restrictions do we have to put on $U$ so that $S(X)/S(A) \rightarrow S(X/A)$ given by the pushout diagram

[image]

(I made a typo, $S(X)$ and $S(A)$ in the top part of the diagram should change place)

is a weak equivalence of simplicial sets whenever $A \rightarrow X$ is a cofibration in $C$?

Giving a satisfactory answer would substantially generalize the result that whenever $A \rightarrow X$ is a cofibration of topological spaces, then the map $H_i(X,A) \rightarrow H_i(X/A,*)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: The first claim is established like in Lemma 15.11.10 in Hirschhorn's Model Categories and Their Localizations (which proves a special case of cofibrant objects).

Comment: Some trivial thoughts: forgetting about the object $U$ for a second, a good class of examples where this happens just for a functor $S: C \rightarrow SSet$ is where (derived) $S$ preserves homotopy pushouts. This will happen when $S$ is a left Quillen functor. However, the motivating example of the singular set functor is not actually a left Quillen functor. It is happening because it is a (right) Quillen equivalence. So I feel like it might be rare that choosing some U actually results in homotopy pushouts being preserved.